# SpringBoot with no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path error

Tags: spring-boot, netty, activemq-artemis

I've got a SpringBoot application that uses a library which uses Apache ActiveMQ Artemis for communication. 
For some reason I've got an error with the following line: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path

I have no clue how to correct this. I readed that in some projects with similar error they add the following lines in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
  <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

But it didn't help.
I've been doing tests changing some dependencies in my pom.xml from the library and from the application but wasn't able to solve the issue.

I include both pom.xml:

the one from the library

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.ems.microservice.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>ems-ms-core-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>EMSMSCoreLibrary</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
  </parent>  


  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
   <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.apm</groupId>
            <artifactId>apm-agent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-manifests</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
           <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The one from the actual application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx.ems.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>ms-disk-loader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MSDiskLoader</name>
    <description>Spring Boot MSDiskLoader project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <ems.ms.core.library.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</ems.ms.core.library.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <docker.image.prefix>ems</docker.image.prefix>
   </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx.ems.microservice.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>ems-ms-core-library</artifactId>
            <version>${ems.ms.core.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>                        
         </plugin>       

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>unpack</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>unpack</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                           <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                           <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                           <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </artifactItem>
                     </artifactItems>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>            
            <configuration>
               <repository>localhost:5000/${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
               <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
               <contextDirectory>.</contextDirectory>
               <tag>${project.version}</tag>
              <pullNewerImage>false</pullNewerImage>   
               <resources>
                  <resource>
                     <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                     <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                     <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                  </resource>
               </resources>
            </configuration>  
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Any clue of what is happening? Is there something else I should install
Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`? Is it in a log message? If so, can you paste the entire log message?

Answer (score 6):

I think you should check the logs. Probably after that exception you will see some thing like:

```
19:02:17.432 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Successfully loaded the library /tmp/libnetty_transport_native_epoll_x86_649039721349137645772.so
```

Which means that everything is fine. Netty tries to load different native implementations on startup. When some implementation fails to load, it will log exception in DEBUG level. Eventually, it will find implementation that successfully loads. There are some related issues reported and closed, like [this one](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8179).